# Updating users' Microsoft profile pictures with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

Our company is migrating user info to our Microsoft tenant. Part of this info includes the profile picture.
Most of the information I am able to update using Set-MSolUser, but for the profile picture I've been trying to use Microsoft Graph, with no success.
I am a tenant admin and yet I've had no success in updating users' profile pictures. Here's my code:

```
$token = [my-token]

$Headers = @{
    "Authorization" = "Bearer $token"
    "Content-Type" = "image/jpeg"
}

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user-id}/photo/$value' -Method Put -Headers $Headers
```

This has just been for test purposes so I'm trying with a single user id and no picture. This has been the output:

```
  "error": {
    "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
    "message": "AccessDeniedException",
```

And the same thing happens when querying directly through the graph website:

[image: error-message-ms-graph]

[Per the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), certain permissions are necessary (contact, group or user read.write) which I have ticked all on the Graph website, but still nothing.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: _Note To update the photo of any user in the organization, your app must have the User.ReadWrite.*All* application permission and call this API under its own identity, not on behalf of a user._ Read the whole docs first.

Comment: I did read that, but I'm honestly no expert in that sense. I found this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service but I don't really understand how to "register an app" when I'm trying to do this from my own PC's PowerShell. Could you clarify please?

Comment: portal.azure.com -> Active Directory -> App Registration -> New Registration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under user permissions you able to edit only your own picture.
You have to create an Azure AD application with `User.ReadWrite.*All*` permission to edit others' pictures.

Go to:
`portal.azure.com -> Active Directory -> App Registration -> New Registration`. Then under `API permissions` you grant `User.ReadWrite.All` and click `grant admin consent`. Then under `Certificates and Secrets` you create an app secret.

```
$AzAppSecret = 'abcDEFghiJKLmnoPQRstuVWXyz01234567'   # from AzureAD -> App Registrations -> YourApp -> Certificates & secrets
$AzAppId     = 'AAAAAAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAA' # from AzureAD -> App Registrations -> YourApp -> Overview -> Application (client) ID
$AzTenantId  = 'BBBBBBBB-BBBB-BBBB-BBBB-BBBBBBBBBBBB' # from AzureAD -> App Registrations -> YourApp -> Overview -> Directory (tenant) ID
$AzUserUPN   = 'username@example.com'                 # from AzureAD -> Users -> YourUser -> User Principal Name
$AzUserImage = 'S:\samplepic.jpg'                     # Jpeg file


# Request token
$tokenRequestBody = @{
        Grant_Type    = "client_credentials"
        Scope         = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
        Client_Id     = $AzAppID
        Client_Secret = $AzAppSecret
    }
$tokenRequestUri = [String]::Format('https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/oauth2/v2.0/token', $AzTenantId)
$tokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $tokenRequestUri -Method 'POST' -Body $tokenRequestBody -ErrorAction Stop
$accessToken = $tokenResponse.access_token

$uri = [String]::Format('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{0}/photo/$value', $AzUserUPN)
$Headers = @{
    'Authorization' = [String]::Format('Bearer {0}', $accessToken)
    'Content-Type'  = 'image/jpeg'
}

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Put -Uri $uri -InFile $AzUserImage -Headers $Headers
```

---

Alternative way:

```
# Load Assembly System.Net.Http
# In PS7 built-in, on PS5 - Download NuGet package from https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http/ and unzip using 7zip
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile('P:\path-to\system.net.http.4.3.4\runtimes\win\lib\netstandard1.3\System.Net.Http.dll')

# Prepare httpClient and URI
$httpClient = [System.Net.Http.HttpClient]::new()
$httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = [String]::Format('Bearer {0}', $accessToken)

# Prepare Content
$content = [System.Net.Http.ByteArrayContent]::new([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($AzUserImage));
$content.Headers.ContentType = "image/jpeg";

# Run
$task = $httpClient.PutAsync($uri,$content)
$task.Wait()
$task.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode
```

---

Remember to keep Application secret private

Comment: My issue now is the auth2.0 token. Would you be so kind tell me how I can get the auth token? I managed to follow the auth2.0 flow and got the "code" necessary for the POST request to get the token, but I keep getting "request malformed". Do I need to do something specific considering this is just for use with a local PowerShell?

Comment: Updated fully working script for single user. There is a some kind of special behaviour: see graph bug https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/3751

Comment: It finally worked. I managed to go through the auth token flow on Postman and got the bearer token from there. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is expected error in case if

- for app using *application permissions*, `User.ReadWrite.All` permission is missing when calling this Microsoft Graph endpoint
- token is acquired with *delegated permissions*

Documentation says the following in this regard:

> update the photo of any user in the organization, your app must have
> the `User.ReadWrite.All` application permission and call this API
> under its own identity, not on behalf of a user

And last but not least, profile image is expected to be passed via request body, in case of PowerShell the request could be constructed like this:

```
$Headers = @{
    "Authorization" = "Bearer $access_token"
    "Content-Type" = "image/jpeg"
}

$url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/$($userId)/photo/$value"
$profilePath = "--path to profile file--" 

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/$($userId)/photo/$value" -Method Put -InFile $profilePath -Headers $Headers
```